# Javascript indexOf() and Underscores

Tags: javascript, indexof

I am returning cookies through a Chrome Extension - one of the `cookies.name` is `use_hitbox` - so naturally I want to do:

```
if (cookie.name.indexOf("use_hitbox") > 0) {
   alert("FOUND HITBOX COOKIE");
}
```

**The Issue is:**
`cookie.name.indexOf("use")` returns `true`
`cookie.name.indexOf("hitbox")` returns `true`
`cookie.name.indexOf("use_hitbox")` returns `false`

Any ideas?

**Disclaimer:**
This is for use on MY site, nothing malicious...!

**EDIT:** Cool, this works - but the underlying issue was Chrome Caching my Extensions file

Comment: If `cookies.name` is `"use_hitbox"` then `indexOf` returns `0` (first character) which is not bigger than `0`. I think you want `... > -1`.

Comment: @FelixKling, 100% true, although then `indexOf("use")` should fail as well. Something doesn't smell right here.

Comment: I am running this in a Chrome Extension - would that make a difference?

Comment: @Neurofluxation: It's unlikely... be sure about the values the variables have.

Comment: There is no reason for the underscore to make any difference. Can you alert(cookie.name) before the if statement to ensure the cookie name is as expected?

Comment: @lamplightdev: Better use `console.log` or `console.dir`.

Comment: I think we are getting distracted on the bad use of `.indexOf` could it be a casing issue? `indexOf()` is case sensitive...

Comment: Cool, this works - but the underlying issue was Chrome Caching my Extensions files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

indexOf() will return 0 if the match is at the beginning of the string. -1 indicates no match so try:

```
if (cookie.name.indexOf("use_hitbox") > -1)
```

Comment: Cool, this works - but the underlying issue was Chrome Caching my Extensions files

Answer (score 1):

Rather than parsing the returned index as `boolean` (which as pointed out, will mean an index of 0 parses as `False`), compare `result != -1`, which is the return value if the substring is not found.